# Mechanics of moving and acting in a completely dark environment

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, vision-and-light

Are there any mechanical consequences in the game for characters without darkvision when moving and taking actions in a completely dark environment (such as a pitch black forest)?

Are there penalties for moving in the dark when you cannot see?

Is it, for example, possible to use a weapon to shoot at a character standing in light if you are in darkness yourself, or would you suffer from not having light to see the path you are walking, load your weapon etc.?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the RPG StackExchange! This site works best when you focus on one specific question at a time. Could you [edit] your post to focus more on just one question that gets to the core of your confusion? If you don't have time to do it now, your question may get put on hold so people won't answer while we wait for your clarifications/edits.

Comment: One question that you seem to be asking is: "Does traveling through a forest in the dark without darkvision or a lightsource have any mechanical consequences?" (or something like that). You may want to focus on that to begin with.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I edited the question so it is more specific and only one question similar to your proposal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Characters in darkness without a light source or darkvision are blind

> Darkness creates a heavily obscured area. Characters face Darkness outdoors at night (even most moonlit nights), within the confines of an unlit dungeon or a subterranean vault, or in an area of magical Darkness.

and

> A heavily obscured area—such as Darkness, opaque fog, or dense foliage—blocks vision entirely. A creature effectively suffers from the Blinded condition (see Conditions ) when trying to see something in that area.

Blinded means is a condition in the game which says:

> A blinded creature can’t see and automatically fails any ability check
> that requires sight. Attack rolls against the creature have advantage,
> and the creature’s Attack rolls have disadvantage.

Now that we have the groundwork laid, I'll apply this to your questions.

## Moving in a dark environment

There are no rules that apply any kind of penalty when moving in darkness without a light source even in a forest or similar environment.

A DM might rule that it is difficult terrain:

> Every foot of movement in difficult terrain costs 1 extra foot.

But there are no rules demanding or recommending this.

If at any time a character would need to make an ability check in the forest that depends on sight while blind they will automatically fail. This will definitely hamper their ability to perceive threats (enemies, dangerous plants) and environmental dangers (pits, tree roots, etc.) if there are any present.

## Attacking in a dark environment (everybody is in darkness)

A creature fighting in the dark that cannot see has disadvantage to hit someone else and advantage to being hit by someone else. If you have two such creatures, the disadvantages and advantages both cancel out meaning that they only roll one d20 to hit like normal.

> If circumstances cause a roll to have both advantage and disadvantage, you are considered to have neither of them, and you roll one d20. This is true even if multiple circumstances impose disadvantage and only one grants advantage or vice versa. In such a situation, you have neither advantage nor disadvantage.

Of course if you can't see the target to begin with, you are going to have to first guess their location before you can hit them.

> When you attack a target that you can’t see, you have disadvantage on the attack roll. This is true whether you’re guessing the target’s location or you’re targeting a creature you can hear but not see. If the target isn’t in the location you targeted, you automatically miss, but the GM typically just says that the attack missed, not whether you guessed the target’s location correctly.
>
> When a creature can’t see you, you have advantage on attack rolls
> against it. If you are hidden—both unseen and unheard—when you make an
> attack, you give away your location when the attack hits or misses.

## Attacking in darkness (target is standing in light)

Note that the blind condition says:

> A creature effectively suffers from the Blinded condition (see Conditions ) when trying to see something **in that area**.

So a creature standing in darkness can see the character in the light. Thus, they can target them normally no guessing or disadvantage. Additionally, since the other creature can't see the one in darkness, the creature has advantage on attacks against the creature in the light since:

> When a creature can’t see you, you have advantage on attack rolls against it.

Answer (score 1):

When you stand in the dark and are hiding you would get advantage, if there are no factors that would impose disadvantage. 
Let's say you stand in the darkness, but you can see far enough to see the person in the light. You would not get any penalties because you can still see them. In terms of loading your weapon, or otherwise using it, you can generally assume that you can competently do that, unless the Dungeonmaster tells you otherwise.

If they stand in darkness then you would get disadvantage in lowlight situations. In complete darkness your Dungeonmaster, unless you are the Dungeonmaster might force you to do a perception roll to detect where your target is.

Mechanically there are no penalties for moving in darkness, but the dm may choose to enforce them regardless, for example treating it as difficult terrain.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it would be much improved if you supported your points with citations and references to the rules so people reading it know where your knowledge is coming from. :)

Answer (score 1):

The way I usually houserule moving in darkness (have since 2nd edition) is that your direction is random (1d8) to determine a compass point) unless you use an action to make a perception check (assuming there is something to hear and help them in a particular direction, ie. sounds of battle) in which case you choose your direction and roll (1d3). A result of 2 = the intended direction while 1 and 3 are diagonals but still generally in the same direction. You could simply say a perception check just points you the right way.

I know that probably sounds overly complicated but we've used this so long its simple to us ;) ... hope that helps.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE and thanks for submitting an answer backed by your group's experience. I'm curious how much this slows down the game. Do you roll a random direction every time someone moves (and so it's possible to wander back and forth endlessly)? Or is it possible to, for example, find a wall and follow it in one direction?